# what is ContentType for Excel 2007

Tags: excel

For downloading `XlSheet` from database  I am using the

```
Response.ContentType =  "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

After downloading the page. When I open the file It is Showing the pop-up Message Called You are Opening Different Format then Specified .

I Think this is a Content type problem.
What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: from which database and which language are your creating your file? what is your code to create this? your question is really unclear. Please edit it to elaborate and add the appropriate tag (Excel won't help much here)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx

Comment: If you're sending the content as HTML but under an Excel MIME type, excel gives this warning.  See - http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/08/11/Excel-Extension-Hardening-and-Web-Applications.aspx

Comment: Thak U jimmuPena.Thank U all For Giving Valuable things